# Regex error "Repetition not preceded by valid expression" in Grep

Tags: regex, grep

I have in a file with strings such as `{?ENV1}` `{?ENV2}`

I want to use grep to find these using

`grep -o '\{\?\S+?\}' myfile`

but I get 
`grep: bad regex '\{\?\S+?\}': Repetition not preceded by valid expression`

in regex101 website the regex works. Is grep working differently?

Comment: use `-P` flag like `grep -o -P '\{\?\S*\}' myfile`

Comment: Escaping braces in BRE context means quantifier in Extended RE or other flavors you used in regex101. So `.{5}` in a flavor in regex101 means `.\{5\}` in BRE.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX `grep` default regex engine is POSIX BRE. You shouldn't escape braces or use `\S`. Former leads to a special meaning (the cause of error you see) and latter isn't supported. Try:

```
grep -o '{?[^{}]*}' file
```

Or to keep `\S` purpose:

```
grep -o '{?[^[:space:]]*}' file
```

Or even to work around `+` quantifier:

```
grep -o '{?[^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-P` flag for Perl based regular expressions(though still in experimental phase)

```
grep -oP '\{\?\S*\}' myfile
```

**OR**

Try this with updated regex. You can use `*`

```
grep -o '\{\?\S*\}' myfile
```

Comment: `grep: unrecognized option: P`

Comment: Which version of grep you are using? are you using MAC?

Comment: BusyBox v1.27.2 (2017-11-28 16:17:30 GMT) multi-call binary. its inside a docker container

Comment: but  I need the + for the regex. The problem with * is that it is doesnt take the minimum, where with ? it does

Comment: what do you mean by minimum. can you give an example?